# How to have a helper text over the input field in html?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have the following design:
[UI Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5MJD.png)

I want an input field like this i.e. having a text like `Shipper Name` or `Contact Number` on top of the input field. How can I achieve this in HTML ? I am not able to find it on the internet.

Thank you

Comment: https://codepen.io/finnhvman/pen/xyOORQ

Answer (score 2):

you can use `material-ui` to access these kind of components without having to code it from scratch.

Their TextField looks exactly the same in the image you provided:
https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/

Their documentation you can follow to integrate their library on your project:
https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/installation/

Comment: I don't want to use Material-UI as I am already using ant design. I don't want to install another library for this requirement only.

Answer (score 0):

Use fieldset and legend

```html
<fieldset><legend>Shipper Name</legend><input type="text"></fieldset>
```